# C++: Is there a way to distinguish a user input if its on centimeter or not?

Tags: c++

Heres the given:

> Write a program to compute for the surface area and volume of a sphere if the unit of the radius
> is in centimeters (cm).
>
> Filename: exer10.cpp
> Formulas: area = `4*pi*radius2`
> Volume = `(4/3)*pi*radius3`

*I was skeptical because of the "if" on the given as you read it, now I don't know if what I did is right. But I have some ideas on how to do it*

I Have a 2 ideas in mind 1st is where if I input a value there will be a formula to distinguish if that value is in centimeter, the thing is I don't know how.

2nd idea is I will use the if else method where after I input a value, it will ask if its in centimeter or not, if  I type "Y" it will do its thing and continue its computation but if I type "N" it`ll will not compute and end the program.
Any suggestion guys?

By the way here's my code (My given ideas are not written here)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

 float radius, area, volume;

 cout << "This program computes for the surface area and volume of a sphere (centimeters)"
 "\n\n";
 cout << "Input the radius of a sphere    : ";
 cin >> radius;

 area = (4 * 3.1416 * radius * radius);
 volume = (4 / 3) * (3.1416 * radius * radius * radius);

 cout << "The surface area of a sphere is : " << area << "\n";
 cout << "The volume of a sphere is       : " << volume;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask the user to use notation like "6cm", "4m", etc. Lots of ways on t'internet on how to do that. P.S. evil definition of *pi* by the way.

Comment: 3rd idea, just change `cout << "Input the radius of a sphere";` to `"Input the radius of a sphere (in centimeters)"` and leave it to the user to comply, since you have no way to check/enforce that anyway.

Comment: Your first idea sounds cool, but it would require a program able to read the user's mind.

Comment: My interpretation of the "if" is "assuming", aka assume that the input is in cm

Comment: bolov has a point. When you print the result you need to specify the units. Consider area of a square: User enters "1". Correct result is 1 cm x cm, *if* user input was in `cm`, and if it wasn't then the area is not 1cm x cm, but doesnt matter because thats not what you have been asked for

Comment: for clarification of requirements of your assignment you best ask your tutor. We can only guess like you. Btw thats what I expect if requirements are not clear. Its a bit sad, but as a customer I don't want the coder to be too creative when they didn't understand what I want, rather they should ask for clarification

Comment: offtopic: `(4 / 3) == 1`

Comment: Sheez I didn't realize that. Now it makes all sense thank you guys!

Comment: This isn't a programming question. You've gotten a poor specification, and the solution is to get more details on what the requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user to input the unit. Consider this example, if it's in `centimeters` then perform the operation/task or else exit the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  int radius;
  std::string unit;

  std::cout << "Enter radius of sphere in centimeters (e.g. 5 cm) : ";
  std::cin >> radius >> unit;

  if (unit != "cm") {
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter in centimeters (e.g. 5 cm)";
    exit(1);
  }
  
  // perform operation

  return 0;
}
```